# W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in android

Tags: android, sockets

Tying push the data from my application to local server.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Socket socket;
 private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";//server ip

 private static final int SERVERPORT = 8000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
private class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In the manifest file I have registered below permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.promission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

> getting below error :

```
  W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
  I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 2066(637KB) AllocSpace 
  objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 73% free, 547KB/2MB, paused 13.469ms total 130.017ms
  W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:487)
  W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:441)
  W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:248)
  W/System.err:     at com.abc.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:85)
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is your server running? On the same Android device your app is running?

Comment: RSI Server is not mobile application . It is local server and running in my laptop.

Comment: I'm assuming you are running this on the emulator. The emulator and the PC are like seperate devices. I don't think you can connect to the same pc through 127.0.0.1. I had a similar issue once and running it on a real phone and connecting through the local network fixed it.

Comment: yes , I am running in emulator. I found local-dev.yaml file in the local RSI server. This file contains http:
    port: 8080
    bindAddress: 127.0.0.1
  rsi:
    basepath: "/rsi/v0"
    obd:
      port: 4000
      bindAddress: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is running on an emulator. If your app uses localhost address 127.0.0.1 it tries to connect to a server also running on that emulator.

If your server is running on the same pc your emulator is running on your app should use ip address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: Sorry I could not able to understand.I need to change ip in android code ?  I just inform to you I can able to see response of http://127.0.0.1:8080 in laptop browser ans emulator browser.

Comment: I do not believe you can use 127.0.0.1 in a browser running in the emulator to connect with a server running on the pc where the rmulator runs.

Comment: 1|generic_x86:/ $ ifconfig                                                                                                                   
lo        Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

Comment: If I want test in mobile , which IP need to set?

Comment: Using wifi: To the ip of the device where your server is running on.

Comment: local server, its running in my laptop.

Comment: please find this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610468/not-able-to-get-local-server-json-response-in-android)for more detail .

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the manifest: PROmission instead of PERmission!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.promission.INTERNET"/>
```

should say

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```